# How to work around animated element rendered as a black square (Chrome bug)?

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-animations, css-transforms, css-gradients

Chromium version 75.0.3770.100 (Official Build) Arch Linux (64-bit).
Also observed on Android in Brave (also based on Chromium 75).

I'm making a spinning square filled with a white gradient:

```css
.spinning {
  animation-name: spinning;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(farthest-corner at 40% 40%, #fff, #f7f7f7 50%, #e8e8e8 75%, #d1d1d1 100%);
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

@keyframes spinning {
  0% { transform: rotate3d(1, -1, 0, -180deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate3d(1, -1, 0, 180deg); }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinning"></div>
```

This works fine on Firefox. However, on Chrome, I initially see a *black* square rather than a white one. It's as if Chrome forgot to render the element's layer. Also, the axis of rotation is slightly off center. When I right-click the square and choose "Inspect", it suddenly realizes the error of its ways and turns white.

It looks like I'm running into [issue 966019](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=966019), which appeared in Chrome 75 or maybe 74 and has been confirmed and assigned, but not yet fixed.

Worth noting:

- A `background-color` *in addition to* the `background-image` makes the square turn that colour rather than black.
- If I put some text inside the div, I get an invisible square rather than a black one.

Workarounds:

- It doesn't happen with `backface-visibility: visible`. But I need it to be hidden because the square in my actual situation has two differently-coloured sides, created by two such spinning squares that are 180 degrees out of phase.
- It doesn't happen with a plain `background-color` *instead of* the gradient. But the gradient is needed to fit in with the rest of the style.
- It doesn't happen if I start the rotation at `0deg` and go through `360deg`. But then it would start at the same moment as the "front" side.

Since all of these have undesirable side effects, I'm looking for a better workaround.

Comment: Could you add a bit about why these are not viable workarounds? How can we be sure that the ones we will provide will be.

Comment: Also, definitely a bug, simply scrolling down until the snippet is barely visible will make it work ;-)

Comment: @Kaiido Good point, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution is to consider pseudo element to create both sides and you won't have the bug and you can easily manage each side alone.

```css
.spinning {
  animation-name: spinning;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
}
.spinning:before,
.spinning:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.spinning:before {
  background-image: radial-gradient(farthest-corner at 40% 40%, #fff, #f7f7f7 50%, #e8e8e8 75%, #d1d1d1 100%);
}
.spinning:after {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  background:rgba(255,0,0,0.5);
}

@keyframes spinning {
  0% {
    transform: rotate3d(1, -1, 0, -180deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate3d(1, -1, 0, 180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinning"></div>
```

Comment: Ooh, that's a nice approach.

Answer (score 0):

One other workaround is to trigger an animation on your element's pseudo-element `content` property:

```css
.spinning {
  animation-name: spinning;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-delay: 0s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  background-image: radial-gradient(farthest-corner at 40% 40%, #fff, #f7f7f7 50%, #e8e8e8 75%, #d1d1d1 100%);

}
.spinning::after {
  content: "";
  animation: trigger-paint .1s forwards 1;
}
@keyframes spinning {
  0% { transform: rotate3d(1, -1, 0, -180deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate3d(1, -1, 0, 180deg); }
}
@keyframes trigger-paint {
  0% {content: ""}
  100% {content: none}
}
```

```html
<div class="spinning"></div>
```

But since the trick here is that it forces a repaint, I fear this comes with huge performance impacts (according to my dev tools, it does restart the animation a whole lot of times, even though it's set to kick on once).

Comment: Interesting thought. It does trigger a repaint, but it takes a while (longer than .1s) for it to kick in, so I still see a black square for a while.

Comment: Ah... I don't. However as I said, looking at the tree view of the dev-tools show that the :after keep toggling infinitely. They definitely have a bug with their paint optimizer. Worths a bug report if there isn't already

Comment: it's also random for me, sometimes I see it, sometimes not

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved it by not relying on `backface-visibility` but rather just animating `visibility` myself:

```css
.spinning {
  animation-name: spinning, hide-backface;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear, step-start;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: radial-gradient(farthest-corner at 40% 40%, #fff, #f7f7f7 50%, #e8e8e8 75%, #d1d1d1 100%);
}

@keyframes spinning {
  0% { transform: rotate3d(1, -1, 0, -180deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate3d(1, -1, 0, 180deg); }
}

@keyframes hide-backface {
  0% { visibility: hidden; }
  25% { visibility: hidden; }
  75% { visibility: visible; }
  100% { visibility: hidden; }
}
```

```html
<div class="spinning"></div>
```